# Produce JSON output from taxonomy tree

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, javascript, ajax

I am trying to return a taxonomy tree in the JSON format but the issue is that I would like to have it nested based on the depth of the term, like the following format:
What is the easiest way to do this?

```
 {
            label: 'term1',
            children: [
                { label: 'term1.1' },
                { label: 'term1.2',
                  children: [label: 'term1.2.1'] }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'term2',
            children: [
                { label: 'term2.1' }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Thanks,

Comment: So, what is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry the question now is clarified. I have tried to modify and the algorithm mentioned in the following link but so far no luck.  http://drupal.org/node/223675